# Handle Dark mode in Material UI redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I have a React app with Material UI. The dark mode basically works, but anytime I try to change the dark mode state on a page where the page is rendered from redux state data, the whole page crashes. I assume because it loses the redux state:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `items` is marked as required in `WarehouseTable`, but its value is `null`.
```

Which is correct because the `Theme` wraps the whole App, so all children object re-render itself.

What I don't know is why the redux state is not preserved. Why it seems that the redux state is lost?

How can I handle this?

Comment: Is this in ssr like nextjs? or normal  react app

Comment: No, normal react app, everything is rendered on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem for me was that the ReduxProvider and the ThemeProvider was rendered in the same function.

So I moved the ThemeProvider to a ReduxProvider child component and this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by moving redux wrapper around the mui wrapper

```
 <ReduxProvider>
  <ThemeProvider>
   <App/>
  </ThemeProvider>
 </ReduxProvider>
```

Comment: This is how I use it also. The redux `Provider` is the main wrapper and I still have problems with it. But if it should work like this, then maybe something else is wrong.